# How to insert a number to string of numbers in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string like: project = '1,2' and I want to insert another number to this string. So for example after the insertion I want to have : project = '1,2,3'
Could you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[`.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) should help you.

```
project = "1,2"
project += ',{}'.format(3)
```

And if you have a position, you could use slicing :

```
project = "1,2,4,5"

position = 3

project = project[:position] + ',3' + project[position:]
```

**EDIT**

I thought about another solution:

```
project += '%s%s' % (',',3)
```

Comment: didn't notice you actually posted this before me. I'll get rid of mine. +1

Comment: The simplest solution tends to be the right one. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
project = '1,2'
n = 3
project = ','.join((project, str(n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the number into string using str() and append division symbol and the number you want to insert

```
project = "1,2"
project += ',' + str(3)
print (project)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert it to a list with `numbers = project.split(",")`.  You can then add another number with `numbers.append('3')`.  Then make a new string with `newproject = ",".join(numbers)`.  Full code:

```
project = "1,2"
numbers = project.split(",")
numbers.append('3')
newproject = ",".join(numbers)
```